# Why i get error "Failed starting 'elasticsearch-service-x64' service" when i try "elasticsearch-service.bat start"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try "elasticsearch-service.bat start" and get error "Failed starting 'elasticsearch-service-x64' service"
My JAVA_HOME[image]

my logs
[image]

Comment: is there is any meaningful in error logs ?

Comment: i think yes. But can you help me?

Comment: Yes, but you need to provide me the error message 